# F# Conditional Expressions if...then..else returning unit or ()

Tags: f#, null, expression, conditional-operator

F#'s Condtional Expressions require a condition to check, a branch for true, and a branch for false. For example:

```
let x = 
    if ("hello" = null) 
    then true
    else false //error if else branch missing
```

However, something gets weird when `unit`, aka `()`, is involved.

```
let y = 
    if ("hello" = null) 
    then raise <| new ArgumentNullException()
    else () //happy with or without else branch
```

And more simply:

```
let z = 
    if ("hello" = null) 
    then ()
    else () //happy with or without else branch
```

Why isn't an`else` branch required when `unit` is returned?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Consider the following code:

```
let f a = if a > 5 then true
```

If you call `f 10`, it returns `true`.

Now, ask yourself this: what should `f 2` return? I know you're going to say `false`, but how does the compiler know that? I mean, it's just as likely that you meant it to return `true` in both cases, isn't it? Or even, perhaps, crash in the `a <= 5` case, who knows?

So in order for the program to be "complete" (i.e. contain instructions for what to do in every situation), you always have to specify an `else` branch.

---

`unit`, however, is *special*.

Returning `unit` means that there is no meaningful return value. Essentially `unit` stands for side-effect: it means that the thing that returned it was meant to produce some effect in the external world. Since F# is not a pure language, such `unit`-returning things are quite ubiquitous. For example, debug logging:

```
let f x =
    if x < 42 then printfn "Something fishy, x = %d" x
    x + 5
```

With such statements, there is no ambiguity: it's always known that the `else` branch is meant to return `()` as well. After all, there are no other values of `unit`, are there? At the same time, always adding `else ()` at the end would be very tiresome and obfuscating. So, in the interest of usability, the compiler doesn't require an `else` branch in this specific case.

Comment: When unit is involved "always adding else () at the end would be very tiresome and obfuscating". I agree, I just expected that would be the decision made - I'm glad it isn't!

Answer (score 5):

In F# `if` is an expression and not a statement. Every expression needs to return a value. And both `if` and `else` need to return same type of value, because F# is strongly typed language. So if there is no `else` branch then by default it has type `unit`, but if your `if` returns a value with a type other than`unit`, then you need to have an `else` with the same type.

Answer (score 2):

> [The types of the values produced in each branch must match. If there is no explicit else branch, its type is unit. Therefore, if the type of the then branch is any type other than unit, there must be an else branch with the same return type.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/conditional-expressions-if-then-else)

If you remove `else` from the first snippet, it's equivalent to

```
let x = 
    if ("hello" = null) 
    then true
    else ()
```

which doesn't typecheck.

Why? I'd guess for compatibility with OCaml.

> [The `else expr3` part can be omitted, in which case it defaults to `else ()`. (7.7.2)](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/expr.html)

You can think of `unit`-returning `if` as an equivalent to the C-like `if` *statement* as opposed to the expression.

Comment: It has nothing to do with compatibility with OCaml.

Comment: In the sense that "if OCaml didn't allow omitting `else` (like SML doesn't), would F#'s designers allow it?" I would expect the answer to be "no, they wouldn't".

Comment: While that may be true, it's not the root of the rationale for this behavior.  If you ignore the relationship with OCaml, there's still a reason for the use of `if` without `else`, as Fyodor's answer explains.

Comment: Plus, there are plenty of things in F# that were added to reduce repetitiveness and don't exist in OCaml, e.g. lightweight syntax.

Comment: It's a question of why _F# in particular_ does this vs why languages with if-expressions tend to do this (even if not always). My best evidence for tradition over principle is that the same reason explained by Fyodor should apply to unit-returning pattern matches: why isn't always having to add `| _ -> ()` "very tiresome and obfuscating"?

Comment: Because it's not nearly as ubiquitous.

Answer (score 2):

*Question already answered so I am just going to follow-up with my own superficial observations*

In F# we don't have statements and expressions. In F# we compose computations using expressions alone. This is a *good* thing.

In C# where `if` is a statement this makes sense

```
if(x)
{
  return 1;
}
```

If `x` is true the execution is stopped and we return to the caller the result: `1`.

In F# where `if` an expression it means that `if` is supposed to produce a value regardless what branch has been taken. Therefore this makes little sense

```
if x then 1 // What value should else branch evaluate to?
```

We have to specify both branches

```
if x then 1 else 0
```

As the other answers indicate there is a special case when `else` is omitted. The `if` expression will produce a `unit` value, the closest thing we get to a statement in F#.
 Because the type of the `if` expression is unit the "true" branch must be of type `unit`.

```
if x then ()         // This works
if x then () else () // This works
if x then 1          // This won't work, type mismatch
```